# Problems with health endpoint when using remote Consul (with OpenShift)

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, microservices, consul

I have a microservice which uses Consul as a service discovery. The pom.xml of my microservice looks as follows (only shows the relevant parts):

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- .... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Besides, my application.yml looks like this:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: test-service
    consul:
        host: localhost
        port: 8500
```

With these settings, I can access the health endpoint after I started consul and my microservice.
However, when I change the consul settings to a consul running on OpenShift, the health endpoint is no longer available. Instead, I get "File not found" when I try to access the health endpoint. However, in the start up log (when startingmyservice locally), I see information concerning the health endpoint:

> ...EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{{/health || /health.json], methods=[GET]..onto ... HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, java.security.Principal)

As soon as I change it back to localhost, it works fine. The same problems occur when I deploy the microservice itself to OpenShift.

Does anyone have an idea what is the reason for this? Apparently, the consul settings influence the healthpoint related behavior.

Comment: What are you setting it to when it isn't ``localhost``?

Comment: I'm setting it to the URL the route of my Consul service (on OpenShift). This basically works, as Consul shows my microservice. But nonetheless, the health endpoint is not working in this case.

Comment: I need to see the exact JSON/YAML in the deployment configuration for the health probe. Not enough for you to just describe it to me.